# Django undetected migrations and "notmigrations" directory

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to add a couple of fields to an existing model. There are two issues.

1) Django is unable to detect changes in my model. when I do `python manage.py makemigrations` I get this message back.

No changes detected.

2) When I try to create the migration manually using `python manage.py makemigrations --empty myapp`, django is creating the migration in a new folder called "notmigrations"

Any thoughts as to what causing this behavior?

I am using

Django 1.7

Comment: is your app listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Yes, it is listed.

Answer (score 1):

you need to "register" your app to migration [says the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/migrations/#adding-migrations-to-apps)

```
python manage.py makemigrations yourapp
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Is there folder `migrations` with file `__init__.py` in it in your application folders?

2) I got same error in Django 1.8 because of this in `settings.py`:

```
class DisableMigrations(object):
    def __contains__(self, item):
        return True
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return "notmigrations"

MIGRATION_MODULES = DisableMigrations()
```

Comment: To fix it in Django 1.11, on `__getitem__` method, just return `None` instead of `notmigrations`.